# Display possible values (choices) of SlugRelatedField in drf-yasg OpenAPI and Swagger views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I have several models that I use as enums (basically, the model is just a name and a slug), like currencies and countries etc, and I'm trying to show the available choices in drf-yasg without success.
My last attempt was adding this to the serializer's Meta class:

```
swagger_schema_fields = {
    'currency': {'enum': list(Currency.objects.values_list('slug', flat=True))}
}
```

But of course it failed miserably - not only it didn't show the enum values, it also broke the serializer (because it used the strings instead of the actual model).

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I added a new field class that does exactly what I needed. I can't promise it's the most efficient way of solving this (retrieving the swagger page seems to take longer) but it does the job:

```
# choices_slug_field.py

from drf_yasg.inspectors import RelatedFieldInspector
from rest_framework.metadata import SimpleMetadata
from rest_framework.relations import SlugRelatedField
from rest_framework.serializers import ManyRelatedField, RelatedField


class ShowChoicesMetadata(SimpleMetadata):
    def get_field_info(self, field):
        field_info = super().get_field_info(field)
        if (not field_info.get('read_only') and
                isinstance(field, (ManyRelatedField, RelatedField)) and
                hasattr(field, 'choices') and
                getattr(field, 'show_choices', False)):
            field_info['choices'] = [
                {
                    'value': choice_value,
                    'display_name': str(choice_name)
                }
                for choice_value, choice_name in field.choices.items()
            ]

        return field_info


class ShowChoicesMixin:
    show_choices = True


class ChoicesSlugRelatedField(ShowChoicesMixin, SlugRelatedField):
    pass


class ShowChoicesFieldInspector(RelatedFieldInspector):
    def field_to_swagger_object(self, field, swagger_object_type, use_references, **kwargs):
        dataobj = super().field_to_swagger_object(field, swagger_object_type, use_references, **kwargs)
        if (isinstance(field, ChoicesSlugRelatedField) and hasattr(field, 'choices')
                and getattr(field, 'show_choices', False) and 'enum' not in dataobj):
            dataobj['enum'] = [k for k, v in field.choices.items()]
        return dataobj
```

Comment: is there any example of how to use it? have you created a PR to DRF/Swagger? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not an actual example nor a PR, but the usage is absolutely straightforward - I just declare fields like this in my serializers (sorry, can't format it any better:

 `myfield = ChoicesSlugRelatedField(queryset=TheModel.objects.all(),
                                                      many=True, slug_field='slug', required=False,
                                                      allow_null=True, allow_empty=True)`

Comment: great! Thanks @pgcd!

Comment: Sorry, and where do you use the `ShowChoicesFieldInspector`?

Comment: You have to add it to `settings.SWAGGER_SETTINGS['DEFAULT_FIELD_INSPECTORS']` - see here: https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/settings.html

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I could make it work! I added it to the desired action using `@swagger_auto_schema(field_inspectors=[ShowChoicesFieldInspector])`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Happy to help, feel free to upvote the answer so it might help somebody.